# Counting records that contain letters given in (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to count records containing given letters, for example column A will contain count of records containing 'a' or 'A', and for E it will be count of records containing 'e' or 'E'. Is there any way to do this by only using grouping functions?

I can do this by using subqueries, but we had this task in class before learning subqueries and I have no idea how to do this by grouping.

The result of the code below that I want to achieve by using grouping:

[image]

```
select
(select count(*) from table where lower(name) like '%a%') as a, 
(select count(*) from table where lower(name) like '%e%') as e
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `count + case` to avoid repeating full-table query select

```sql
select count(case when lower(name) like '%a%' then 1  end) as a
   ,count(case when lower(name) like '%e%' then 1 end) as e
from Table
```

Comment: . . Your `COUNT()`s will return the same values for both columns, and the same as `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: you need to return `null` in the else part to count properly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,@Gordon Linoff  thanks,i forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

The proper expression uses `sum()`:

```
select sum(case when lower(name) like '%a%' then 1 else 0 end) as num_a,
       sum(case when lower(name) like '%e%' then 1 else 0 end) as num_e
from t;
```

You can also use regular expressions (although they are probably more expensive than `like` for this purpose):

```
select sum(case when regexp_like(name, '[aA]') then 1 else 0 end) as num_a,
       sum(case when regexp_like(name, '[eE]') then 1 else 0 end) as num_e
from t;
```